# Getting error in jest for the text inside condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am learning how to write test cases using jest. I have a react file where I have some text or button inside condition. Now when am getting error for the text. But, without condition, it's working. Below is the ts file:

```
{fileErr === '1' && <Text mt={2}>Please fix the issue before continuing.</Text>}
          {fileErr === '2' && <Text mt={2}>For more information see&nbsp;<Link href={faqUrl} target="_blank">FAQ.</Link><br/>Do you want to continue?</Text>}
{fileErr === '2' &&
             (<Button rightIcon={<MdArrowForward />} onClick={onContinue}>
              Continue
            </Button>)}
```

And below are the test case for this:

```
expect(getByText(/Selected define version 2.0 does not match the version in: ./i)).toBeInTheDocument()
expect(getByText(/The following files are missing - make sure they are within the required folder structure as mentioned below./i)).toBeInTheDocument()
const continueButton = getByText(/^Continue$/i)
userEvent.click(continueButton)
```

Now, when I run the test cases, I am getting below error:

*TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /Continue/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.*

Please provide me better solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```js
const continueButton = getByText(/Continue/i)
```

or

```js
const continueButton = getByText((content, element) => {
  // Perform custom logic to match the text
  return content.startsWith('Continue')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but both of these are not working